# Как выделить весь текст внутри тэга?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, webstorm

К приверу у меня есть большая форма, у нее есть тэги к примеру

```
<TableCell> ТУТ большое количество разных букв</TableCell>
<TableCell> ТУТ большое количество </TableCell>
<TableCell> ТУТ большое букв</TableCell>
<TableCell> ТУТ большое количество </TableCell>
<TableCell> ТУТ большое количество разных букв</TableCell>
```

Я хотел бы удалять по одному содержимому тэга за раз, все содержимое, пока что у меня это делается очень непродуктивно, я пользуюсь vim и просто жму выделение и веду ползунок до края и удаляю, могу конечно сразу удалить все содержимое после открытого тэга а потом закрыть, но все же лучше бы иметь нормальную команду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Delete Inner Tag*: [`dit`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#it)

`dat` также удалит всё содержимое и сами теги, а `cit` сразу войдёт в режим редактирования и т.д.

Comment: каааааеф, будто Илоном Маском стал по продуктивности. Спасибо большое!