# Скопировать содержимое html-тэгов в VIM

Tags: vim

Есть веб-страница с тегами.

Необходимо, «выдернуть» содержимое между определенными тэгами(href) и скопировать в новый документ.
Пробовал так:

```
:g/href/y
```

Потом, `:e new.txt p.`
Проблема в том, что копирует только одну строку.
Все остальные не копирует. (копирует также с тэгам href)
Просьба помочь в решении данного вопроса.

```html
<h2 class="какой-то класс"><a href="http://mysite.ru">Содержимое1</a>
<span class="какой-то класс" title="заголовок"><a href="http://mysite.ru">Содержимое2</a></span>
</h2>
<p><a href="http://mysite.ru">Содержимое3</a></p>
  
Файл новый  new.txt
Содержимое1;Содержимое3
Содержимое2
Содержимое1;Содержимое3
Содержимое2
.......................
.......................
.......................
Содержимое1;Содержимое3
Содержимое2
```

Comment: не совсем дубликат, но почти: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1187025/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%8d%d0%b3%d0%b0/1187097#1187097

Comment: приведите репрезентативный пример текста, и что вам нужно из него скопировать. Сейчас непонятно, в частности `href` это не тег, а атрибут, что значит `между тегами href` - для меня загадка.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Не добавляйте, пожалуйста, лишние метки в вопрос. Ваш вопрос не касается самого атрибута `href` или особенностей `html`. Ваш вопрос именно о `vim`. Вместо html в вашем примере может быть любой текст. Метки вроде `cut` и `paste` тоже не несут особой смысловой нагрузки, по ним не ищут вопросы.

Comment: Во-первых, у вас в примере html не well-formed, т.к. тег a во второй строчке не закрыт. Это так и задумано или опечатка? Во-вторых, неясно что в результате должно быть? Две строчки и в каждой написано Содержимое? Или все же там опечатка, т.е. тег должен быть закрыт и нужно получить текст с трема строками? Если так, то тут вы хотите достать содержимое из тега a. Или вы хотите достать содержимое атрибутов href в тегах a? Или вам нужно весь тег `a` со всеми атрибутами? Или вам нужна вся строка где есть тег `a`, включая другие теги (не `a`)? Напишите ожидаемый результат в общем.

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Исправил все отпечатки в тексте.

Comment: Почему в результате строки Содержимое1 и т.д. повторяются много раз? Почему в результате после Содержимое1 стоит двоеточие, а после Содержимое2 и Содержимое3 нет?

Comment: Здравствуйте.
1) Приведенные 3 строчки HTML кода повторятся на сайте несколько десятков раз(только содержимое все время разное)
2) Поэтому необходима выборка СОДЕРЖИМОГО, которая повторяется много раз. (по числу повторений выше приведенного HTML кода)
3) Между Содержимое1 и Содержимое3 стоят точка с запятой.
Данная структура, необходима для удобства дальнейшей обработки.
С Уважением.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение в интернете своего вопроса, правда  с использованием sed и необходимо сделать дополнительные операции: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/13055493.

Вот ответ:

Если нужно просто убрать html-теги, то, например, так:

sed 's/<[^>]*>/ /g;s/<.*//;s/[^>]*>//' < file.html

Здесь используются 3 регулярки для sed:

1.

s/<[^>]*>/ /g;

удаляет все символы между < и >, включая их самих и заменяет всё это на 1 пробел (пробел нужен, чтобы текст, расположенный внутри разных тегов, не слипался, если он не отделён от тегов пробелом). Флаг g обозначает, что делаем это многократно в каждой строке.

2.

s/<.*//;

на тот случай, если некоторые теги занимают 2 строки, удаляем всё, начиная от открывающего тега (все теги, имевшие закрывающий тег в той же строке, уже удалены, поэтому ничего лишнего удалено не будет). Заменяем на пустую подстроку (здесь нечему слипаться, поэтому пробел не нужен). Флаг g тоже не нужен, т. к. удаляем до конца строки, т. е. 1 раз.

3.

s/[^>]*>//

то же самое, но для окончания тега, начатого на другой строке.

Недостаток этого скрипта в том, что он корректно удаляет однострочные и двухстрочные html-теги, но вот трёх- и более строчные не удалит. Точнее удалит только первую и последнюю строку. Кроме того, он не удаляет комментарии и ява- и пхп- скрипты.

Но общий шаблон для самого простого случая я, надеюсь, дал.

Ресурс ответа:
https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/13055493

Второй вариант удаление HTML тэгов:

sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba'  file.html

Проверено работает с HTML.
Не работает с java.